# add mapbox style layer to folium chorpleth

Tags: python, mapbox, folium

I'm trying to add a layer, with name so I can use it with the layer controls, that's from a mapbox style.
I tried unsuccessfully this

folium.Map(
style='mapbox://styles/***************************/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk. * * * * * * * * * * *'
,attr="Mapbox attribution"
,name="new layer"
).add_to(m);

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203062/using-mapbox-tiles-with-folium